# RDF Data Cubes, AttributeProperty, units of measurement & QUDT

Tags: sparql, rdf, vocabulary, data-cube

I'm doing some work with RDF Data Cubes vocabulary for publishing time-series of various data, among others sensors. The measurement of the sensor is taken at a specific time at a specific station.

Both time and station I will model as `qb:DimensionProperty`, the measurement itself as `qb:MeasureProperty`. I would also like to state what unit the measurement is in. In this particular example it is atmospheric pressure at the height of the station. My understanding [from the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/vocab-data-cube/#reference-components) is that this would be modeled as `qb:AttributeProperty`.

In the description of the data structure I would have something like this:

```
<dsd/prestas0> a qb:DataStructureDefinition ;
    qb:component 
        [ qb:dimension  <stn>; qb:order 1 ],
        [ qb:dimension  <time>; qb:order 2 ],
        [ qb:attribute <unit>; qb:order 3 ],
        [ qb:measure  <prestas0>; qb:order 4 ] .

<stn> a qb:DimensionProperty ;
    rdfs:label "Station°" .

<time> a qb:DimensionProperty ;
    rdfs:label "Time" .

<unit> a qb:AttributeProperty ;
    rdfs:label "Unit" ;
    rdfs:comment "The unit of the measurement" .

<prestas0> a qb:MeasureProperty ;
    rdfs:label "Measurement" ;
    rdfs:range xsd:float .

# Units in use

<hPa> a qudt:Unit ;
    rdfs:label "Atmospheric pressure (hPa)" ;
    rdfs:comment "Atmospheric pressure on station level" ;
    rdfs:subClassOf unit:Pascal .
```

As you can see I also created an instance of a unit, called `<hPa>`. In there I use `rdfs:subClassOf` to subclass from [QUDT](http://www.qudt.org/qudt/owl/1.0.0/unit/Instances.html#Pascal) `unit:Pascal`.

Now my questions:

- is my understanding of using `qb:AttributeProperty` for the unit correct?
- Is it fine to sublass from QUDT the way I did? I am aware that I have hPa while QUDT defines Pa only so I would probably have to change the data accordingly
- Can I in general simply use units from QUDT directly (in terms of their URIs) if they do not need a specific tailoring like I did in this example?

Comment: 1. It seems that in general *yes*, but how `<unit>` and `<hpa>` are connected? 2. I think *no*, this is not a subclass relation. 3. Yes, of course.

Comment: 2: Yeah that was just one I would use, they are not linked in the definition itself. I talked to some more people meanwhile, will answer the question myself.

Comment: I agree with @StanislavKralin. The missing connection is `<unit> rdfs:range <hpa> .`.